# Is double-checked locking thread-safe in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, language-lawyer

The [double-checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) idiom is not reliable in some languages, and I want to know whether Python is one of them. More concretely, is the following code...

```py
# Objects shared by threads:
obj = None
lock_for_obj = threading.Lock()

def get_obj():
    """Function called concurrently by threads."""
    if obj is None:
        with lock_for_obj:
            if obj is None:
                obj = factory()  # Never returns `None`
    return obj
```

...thread-safe in Python? Are there scenarios/implementations where it is/isn't? Why?

Comment: You're assuming it's safe to perform lookups on the cache while another thread is modifying it. Even with the GIL (and not all Python implementations have a GIL), that's not completely safe.

Comment: @user2357112: What cache?  The processor cache?  I’m willing to believe that a GIL-less implementation might have different safety rules, but if the GIL didn’t provide cache coherence, wouldn’t *everything* be broken in CPython?

Comment: @DavisHerring ah, they were responding to a previous version of the question which I've edited away.

Comment: @BrianRodriguez: Hm.  The original version of your question had a very interesting answer for CPython, at least as long as the call to `factory` has no side effects (outside the object being created).

Comment: `obj is None` is a read of `obj` and `return obj` is another one, so there’s a possible code path doing two reads of `obj` without any synchronization actions. This could fail even with languages where double checked locking works; they usually require reading `obj` into a local variable to be used for the test and return, so that the code path without synchronization action bears only one read operation.

Comment: That pattern is unsafe (any serious analysis shows why) unless additional mechanisms add some additional guarantees about read/write ordering at the low level. I haven't seen anything like that in official documentation.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica: With the GIL, that's completely safe; the GIL doesn't just protect reference count modifications, it also prevents the normal issues with simple reads; there are no torn or invalid values to be read. Not going to make any claims about non-GIL-ed interpreters though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [PEP 583 - Concurrency memory model for Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0583/), which was withdrawn.

I guess the reason it was withdrawn (though I can't find enough information on that) is since there are [different implementations of Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonImplementations), and it's difficult to enforce a standard like this on every one of them.

Conclusion: this code might be safe when using CPython implementation on a single processor, or it might be safe to use it in general using Jython implementation, but there's no guarantee.